# Unable to sort by date the select queries having union

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to sort by date ,

```
select B.setid,B.date as datevalue ,B.orderid,B.ordertype from table1 B where B.status='ERR' and B.orderid not in (select distinct A.orderid from table1 A where A.status='CMPL' ) group by B.setid,B.date,B.orderid,B.ordertype 
union
select B.setid,B.date as datevalue ,B.orderid,B.ordertype from table2 B where B.status='ERR' and  B.orderid not in (select distinct A.orderid from table2 A where A.status='CMPL' ) group by B.setid,B.date,B.orderid,B.ordertype
order by datevalue desc;
```

datevalue label is common in both select queries but I'm not able to sort by date descending.
Sql is written in Oracle.

Comment: **a)** that's an invalid query, **b)** what is DATEVALUE's datatype? If it is a *string*, no wonder you can't properly sort it (you'd have to convert it to a valid DATE datatype value using TO_DATE function with appropriate format model)

Comment: Why do you `GROUP BY`?

Comment: "I'm not able to sort" doesn't tell us much - do you get an error, or wrong results? Please provide a [mre], not code with other errors that we couldn't run even if we had sample data and knew what the result should be.

Comment: Take smaller steps. First make one of the selects work. Then do the union. Finally add the order by.

Comment: @AlexPoole I'm getting output but not in a date sorted format

Comment: I'm using this in both select query MAX(TO_CHAR(AB.DATETIMEVALUE,'DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM')) as DATEVALUE @Littlefoot

Comment: As I said - that's a string, and strings won't properly format dates. You should be using **DATE** datatype.

Comment: CAST(timestamp_expression AS DATE)  this done the trick , im able to sort using union thanks all :)

Answer (score 0):

try using the original field name in the ORDER BY clause like b.date

or try the below query , it will work:

select tst.setid, tst.datevalue, tst.orderid, tst.ordertype from (
select B.setid,B.date as datevalue ,B.orderid,B.ordertype from table1 B where B.status='ERR' not in
(select distinct A.orderid from table1 A where A.status='CMPL' ) group by B.setid,B.date,B.orderid,B.ordertype
union
select B.setid,B.date as datevalue ,B.orderid,B.ordertype from table2 B where B.status='ERR' not in
(select distinct A.orderid from table2 A where A.status='CMPL' ) group by B.setid,B.date,B.orderid,B.ordertype
) as tst
group by tst.setid, tst.datevalue, tst.orderid, tst.ordertype
order by tst.datevalue desc;

Comment: this didnt worked , tried

Comment: CAST(timestamp_expression AS DATE) this done the trick , im able to sort using union thanks all :)